# Mount horizontal 6" metal exhaust pipe to wall economically?

Tags: hvac, pipe, ducts

I'm trying to add more ventilation to the back room of my garage. The only available outside air exit location is 25' horizontally along the front room of the garage's wall.

I have 6" 30ga sheet metal vent pipe like this for the ducting:

[image]

How would I go about securing it to the wall? All of the hangers and clamps I've seen are either nuts expensive or designed to support the pipe from above (ceiling), not from the wall.

I can't support it from the ceiling as it would interfere with the garage door mechanism.

Comment: If you have room for the pipe then you probably have room for a stack of 6" shelves. The pipe can be supported by the framing and hidden between shelves. You know you're going to pile stuff on the pipe anyway.

Answer (score 3):

A cheap option, is hanger strap.

[enter link description here http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/300/0f/0f824744-2554-4da0-91c2-cad95ee94416_300.jpg](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/300/0f/0f824744-2554-4da0-91c2-cad95ee94416_300.jpg)

It's available in both metal and plastic, and in various sizes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care how it looks, just put some screw eyes in the wall above where you want the duct work to be, and loop some wire around the duct work and attach both ends to the screw eye.  Quick and easy.

As an aside comment, if there is a significant difference in temperatures between the air going through the duct work and the air outside, you may want to consider insulating the duct work to prevent condensation and possible mold/mildew buildup.

Scott

Answer (score 1):

I like PVC strap tape. You can hang it about anywhere with about anything. It doesn't kink up like metal, and it isn't sharp.

[image]